# Stage object won't center and scale to be same on every screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I have 2 questions which both seem should be easy.

First, I am working on a LibGDX game but one of my Table objects won't center

```
Table table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.add(preview).size(preview.getWidth(), preview.getHeight()).center().padBottom(40);
    table.row();
    table.add(last).size(last.getWidth(), last.getHeight()).center().left().padLeft(250);
    table.add(next).size(next.getWidth(), next.getHeight()).center().right().padRight(250);
```

I tried the code above but it turns out like (I want the Level Preview centered)

[image]

---

Question 2

On my phone these images all fit perfectly. but on this phone they are smaller, How would i scale it to be the same size on every phone, is it something with FitViewPort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1:**

Change

`table.add(preview).size(preview.getWidth(), preview.getHeight()).center().padBottom(40);`

to

`table.add(preview).size(preview.getWidth(), preview.getHeight()).center().padBottom(40).colspan(2);`

**Question #2:**

The `FitViewport` may lead to black bars, but the images scale in relation to the aspect ratio. Try using the `StretchViewport` instead, if you want to scale your images in relation to the phone size.

Comment: For the first one how can i have it only center the preview, because it centered my next and last buttons too.

Comment: Maybe remove the `padLeft` and `padRight` or `center()` settings. Use `table.debug()` to see how the table is drawn.

Comment: Thanks and for question 2, i create a StreatchViewport and give it my height and width? How do i apply it to everything

Comment: Yes, I would do it using [this class](https://gist.github.com/reime005/553b3a327702cdb89e095e5d2d1ba996). Something like `public class MyStage extends AbstractStretchStage`

Answer (score 1):

To get the preview Image centered, it's cell needs to span all the columns. It is unnecessary to try to size the cell to the Image if you want the image to exactly fit.

And if you want the two buttons right at the middle, make each of their cells as wide as possible and bias them toward the side of the cell that is at the middle.

So do this:

```
table.setFillParent(true);
table.add(preview).colSpan(2).expandX().center().padBottom(40);
table.row();
table.add(last).expandX().right();
table.add(next).expandX().left();
```

ScreenViewport is nice for UI stages because it results in nice crisp text. But the downside is that you need to have multiple UI asset sizes ready to load depending on the device resolution.

Alternatively you can use ExtendViewport for your UI so you only need one asset scale.

The rest of the viewport classes are junk (IMO):

- FitViewport creates black bars (your users won't like this because phone screens are too small as it is). It's OK if you're using it for the UI layer, but then you need a different viewport to apply for everything else before you draw your UI. And maybe if you're doing a cutscene where black bars are forgivable, you could temporarily use one.
- StretchViewport results in ugly deformed stretching.
- FillViewport results in part of your virtual viewport size being cropped off so you have to do all kinds of math to make sure your scene is fully visible on all devices.

Comment: So for ExtendViewport i just put it where i initialize the stage ExtendViewport vp= new ExtendViewport(width, height, camera), and Stage s = new Stage(vp), then in my render method sb.setProjectionMatrix(vp.getCamera().combined)? Im new to viewports

Comment: Depends if you're using the sprite batch for anything besides the stage. If you're exclusively drawing with Stage, then it takes care of the viewport and camera stuff. But you must always update the viewport in `resize()`